# What is the best way to apply query strings in eloquent where statements?

Tags: php, laravel, search, query-string

Imagine we have some query-strings like this:

- `?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3..`

I am using the following script, but I know that it is not a standard way to do it, and the best, actually it is the worst I have ever seen/done!

#### Searching a file in database:

```
    $data = [
        'files' => File::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(12),
    ];

    //Adding query strings
    if (!empty($request->search)) {

        $replacement_data = [
            'files' => File::where('name','LIKE',"%$request->search%")->paginate(12),
        ];

        return view ("manage.Files.index")->withData(array_replace($data,$replacement_data));

    }

    else {
        return view ("manage.Files.index")->withData($data);
    }
```

Now my question is clear, how can I use these query strings as a filter in the SQL/Eloquent where statements?

Comment: Use laravel's scopes to filter Files through request data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate your query dynamically. The way I did in my project is by dependency injecting the Model class.

```
private $model;

public function __construct(File $model)
{
    $this->model = $model;
}

public function search(Request $request) {

    $query = $this->model;

    // add query string to limit search or ..
    if (!empty($request->search)) {
         $query = $query->where('name','LIKE',"%$request->search%");
    }

    $data['files'] = $query->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(12);

    return view ("manage.Files.index")->withData($data);

}
```

Comment: I think this is more better 
$query = $query->where('name','LIKE',"%".$request->get('search',null)."%");

Comment: If the search term is not passed in the request, that doesn't mean the user wants to search by 'null'. Your query will return incorrect results rather than returning all the files.

Comment: In you case also value will going blank if nothing is entered in search

Comment: No, try it out. It is equivalent to `File::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(12);`